# How to get offset of a Regex capture?

Tags: .net, regex, offset

I'm trying get the offset of a regex capture in .NET just like `.IndexOf()` would return. Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of the `Regex.Match` will be a `Match` object. Check the Index property of that

```
Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
int i = m.Index;
```

hth